# How do I manipulate an existing collection in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable with a jQuery collection in it, like this:

```
$collection = $(".example");
```

This gives me a bunch of nodes with the class "example".

Now, I want to manipulate that collection and retain the results, which I thought would work like this:

```
$(".example", $collection).filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.  Anytime I add an assignment to it, like this:

```
$collection = $(".example", $collection).filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

I get an empty collection.

The end result I want is to have all of the .example class even items in the $collection collection to have the class "even".  I don't want to replace the contents of $collection with only the even .example elements.

Comment: What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated OP with more info about what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$collection.filter(":even").addClass("even");
or
$(".example").filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

When you defined `$collection = $(".example");` what you were doing with
`$(".example", $collection)` was looking for items with the example class inside of items with the example class.

Better yet:

```
$(".example:even").addClass("even");
```

... would be even little more direct.

Update:

```
$collection.filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

Doing this won't overwrite the `$collection` variable.

Comment: +1. And for the OP: use `$collection = $collection.filter(":even").addClass("even")` if the idea is to update the `$collection` variable to hold only the even elements.

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear in the OP. $collection will contain a bunch of nodes with the class "example".  I now want to manipulate only those nodes, while keeping the collection in the variable.  if I filter, I end up removing the nodes that don't match the filter which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add `even` class to even elements in your html you can use this

```
$('.example:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".example", $collection)` selects elements with class `.example` which are **inside** `$collection` node. Try use only `$(".example")`.